# Error:org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.forProjectDirectory(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/lang/Appendable;)Lorg/gradle/wrapper/WrapperExecutor;

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I upgraded my Android Studio to version 2.3 and I began to get this error:

```
Error:org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.forProjectDirectory(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/lang/Appendable;)Lorg/gradle/wrapper/WrapperExecutor;
```

All my projects refused to build; both the ones using gradle  3.3 or any other version.

Before the update everything was working smoothly.

Please how do I fix this?

EDIT: SCreenshot

[image]

Comment: You are using BBQlinux huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all experimental or newish linux builds, there are things that break. You need to make sure that both `/opt/android-sdk` and `/opt/android-studio` (if those are indeed still your paths) have `root:users` ownership and *most* files and directories need 775, others 755, and some files require 664 permissions. Of course you need to belong to `users` group. Listing every detail is, quite honestly and no offense, not worth the points. Best thing you can do to get it right is to create a virtual machine with the same ISO and check both ownerships and permissions after a fresh install. If you still get errors (most surely regarding install properties files), dig deep inside `/opt/android-sdk` and the component you are trying to install and change the file permission to 775.

Hope this helps you. I went through the same hassle just now.

Comment: Oh!. Also delete the gradle and .gradle folders